# Does bean/pea milk made by just blending cooked beans/peas come out just as well as making it by blending soaked beans/peas and boiling them?

Tags: veganism, cooking, beans, milk

So I am vegan and make my own bean and pea milk using mostly Northern White beans and green split peas(finding the yellow ones is a bit hard). I have not made soymilk yet. Anyway, the way I make the bean/peamilk is by cooking them in a crockpot, then blending them in my Nutribullet. I also usually add bananas, sugar, and/or fat(cooking oil/Crisco).

But from what I heard and seen, most people make Bean/peamilk by soaking them overnight, and then blending them and boiling it and filtering it.

Does just cooking and blending get the same result as if I 'properly' made the milk?

Comment: why don't you try it and see how it turns out?

Answer (score 1):

The filtering is done to remove the fibrous (indigestible) part of the beans. If you don't filter the mixture, the result is going to be more viscous, depending on the fibre content, dilution etc. The result might also be less smooth, depending on the quality of your blender and how you use it.

Whether the difference is a problem depends on your use case. It sounds like you're making a smoothie, so it doesn't matter. If you're making a cup of coffee, maybe it does.